# Zenity won't render Unicode characters

Tags: unicode, zenity

I'm trying to run a simple Zenity dialog where I catch user's input:

`zenity --forms --title="Title" --add-entry="Comment"`

When I write in ASCII characters it catches them just fine, however, I when I the input contains Unicode characters (namely Hebrew) it outputs them as question marks. 
I know for sure that it's Zenity's fault, as if I try to change the title as following: `--title="שלום"` it would fail to launch altogether.

I'm running on Ubuntu Xenial with all latest patches. Zenity version is 3.18.1.1.

Comment: I've tried it on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 with the exact same version of Zenity and it works fine so Zenity itself might not be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit to be Ubuntu's locale settings. 
All I had to do to fix this was:

```
$ sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
$ sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en.UTF-8
```

And reboot.

**Edit**
As suggested, I'll elaborate a little bit about this fix:

- Before changing those values, running `locale` would show both LANG and LANGUAGE empty.
- Typing in Hebrew in terminal would result in question marks.
- Nothing in the system seems to have changed, except that now Hebrew can be used in terminal and Zenity.

Comment: This could be a better answer.  It would be interesting to know what it was before you changed it, why it was changed and what program(s) now no longer work correctly.